# C# Regex split by delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, split

I`m facing with regex split problem.

Here is my pattern

```
string[] words = Regex.Split(line, "[\\s,.;:/?!()\\-]+");
```

And this is text file:

```
ir KAS gi mus nugales.
jei! mes MIRTI NEBIJOM,
JEIGU mes nugalejom mirti
DZUKAS
```

And I have a task to find last word in upper, here is code:

```
z = words.LastOrDefault(c => c.All(ch => char.IsUpper(ch)));
```

When in end of the line is some kind of delimiter, it just dont print `z` . When there are no delimiter (3th, 4th lines), everything is going fine..

Why does it happen?

Comment: Your current code should output `DZUKAS`, right? What delimiter do you mean? Also, why not split with `\W+`, or just match with `\p{Lu}+` and get the last match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to find word in uppercase in each line. DZUKAS is one of them, just like KAS (1st line), MIRTI (2nd)

Comment: See https://ideone.com/lJQHaO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not *match* the words (not split), and take the last one?

```
  string source = @"ir KAS gi mus nugales.
                    jei!mes MIRTI NEBIJOM,
                    JEIGU mes nugalejom mirti
                    DZUKAS";

  // or @"\b\p{Lu}+\b" depending on letters you want being selected out
  string pattern = @"\b[A-Z]+\b";

  string result = Regex
    .Matches(source, pattern)         
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .LastOrDefault();
```

**Edit:** If I understand your requirements right (`Regex.Split` *must* be preserved, and you have to output the last all caps letters word *per each line*),  you're looking for something like this:

```
  var result = source
    .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(line => Regex.Split(line, "[\\s,.;:/?!()\\-]+"))
    .Select(words => words
       .Where(word => word.Length > 0 && word.All(c => char.IsUpper(c)))
       .LastOrDefault());

  // You may want to filter out lines which doesn't have all-ups words:
  // .Where(line => line != null);
```

Test

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output

```
  KAS
  NEBIJOM
  JEIGU
  DZUKAS
```

Please notice, that `.All(c => char.IsUpper(c))` includes *empty string case*, that's why we have to add explicit `word.Length > 0`. So you've faced not `Regex` but *Linq* problem (*empty string* sutisfies `.All(...)` condition).

Comment: I know.. there is easier way.. but by the task I MUST use regex split

Comment: This `"[A-Z]+"` will also "extract" `CA` in `CAlifornia`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: Thank you, I see, `\b` is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string s = @"ir KAS gi mus nugales.
jei!mes MIRTI NEBIJOM,
JEIGU mes nugalejom mirti
DZUKAS";
            Match result = Regex.Match(s, "([A-Z]+)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

            Console.WriteLine(result.Value);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've commited the same error: `CA` in `CAlifornia` will match (see Wiktor Stribiżew comments on my answer)

Answer (score 0):

From the question and comments it's hard to figure out what you want but I'll try to cover both cases.

If you're looking for the last word in whole text that is uppercase you can do something like this :

```
Regex r = new Regex("[,.;:/?!()\\-]+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string result = r.Replace(source, string.Empty).Split(' ').LastOrDefault(word => word.All(c => char.IsUpper(c));
```

If you want to find the last match from each line :

```
Regex r = new Regex("[,.;:/?!()\\-]+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string[] result = r.Replace(source, string.Empty).Split(Environment.NewLine).Select(line => line.Split(' ').LastOrDefault(word => word.All(c => char.IsUpper(c)).ToArray();
```

**EDIT:**

Comment: It's quite OK to mention `.` within `[]` as it's done in the question; you don't have to *escape* `.` in the context.